# htaccess RewriteCond for subdirectory not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my .htaccess file written as such for my main program in the top directory but also want to exclude a sub-folder where I want to run another program.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond {REQUEST_URI} !=/ecart
RewriteRule ^files/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?layers=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am trying the RewriteCond but it's not working. 
It should go to the ecart/index.php file but still I am being brought to the front domain when I put my address in as www.mydomain.com/ecart

Answer (score 1):

Your code has syntax error with logical errors. `{REQUEST_URI}` has missing `%` sign and RewriteCond is applicable to next RewriteRule only. Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ecart(/.*|)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /index.php?layers=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: With that I just get an internal Server Error 500 on all of my pages.

Could it be because the site is https and the directory is not?

Comment: Ah there was a typo. Can you try again now.

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.